# Reading XML string from database and parse using Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

Here is a piece of jquery code from my html page

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'userlist.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'id='+extr,
                success: function(results){                 
                    $("#uservidshow").text("Page Title: "+$(results).find("vidlist").attr("title"));
                    //$("#uservidshow").text(results);
                    $(results).find("vids").each(function(){                    
                    $("#uservidshow").append("<br/><br/>Video Name: "+$(this).attr("vtitle")+"<br/>Link: "+$(this).attr("link")+"<br/>Description: "+$(this).find("descr").text()+"<br/><br/>");
                    });                 
                }
            });
```

**--- Here is the output that gets displayed in div#uservidshow ---**

> Page Title: undefined
>
> Video Name: Kids video
>
> Link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIchX1LX0
>
> Description:

---

My question is:

- Why do I get 'undefined' page title?
- Why do i get a blank under the description instead of displaying cdata content?

---

**--- Here is a piece of code from userlist.php ---**

```
<?php

$getid=$_POST['id']; 

....
[few lines of code]
....
            $pickfrmtab= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE userid='$getid'");    
            if(mysql_num_rows($pickfrmtab)==1){
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pickfrmtab)){
                    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['pagecontent'], ENT_QUOTES); //'pagecontent' contains my xml string 
                }           
            }else{
                echo "Unable to get PLAYLIST";
            }           

?>
```

**--- Here is the XML string that is stored in database under the column name 'pagecontent'---**

```
&lt;?xml version=&#039;1.0&#039; encoding=&#039;UTF-8&#039; ?&gt;&lt;vidlist title=&#039;My Fav Videos&#039;&gt;
&lt;vids link=&#039;http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIchX1LX0&#039; vtitle=&#039;Kids video&#039;&gt;
&lt;descr&gt;&lt;![CDATA[this is nice]]&gt;&lt;/descr&gt;
&lt;/vids&gt;
&lt;comment allow=&#039;no&#039;&gt;&lt;/comment&gt;
&lt;/vidlist&gt;
```

---

As you might have guessed, i have applied htmlspecialchars() to the actual xml string before inserting it into database

```
$xmldata="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>".$_POST['actualxmlstrng']; 
$xmldata_safe=htmlspecialchars($xmldata, ENT_QUOTES);
//inserted $xmldata_safe into the datacbase field 'pagecontent' SUCCESSFULLY
```

Just to give you an idea, this is what **$xmldata** looks like before applying htmlspecialchars:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<vidlist title='My Fav Videos'>
<vids link='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIchX1LX0' vtitle='Kids video'>
<descr><![CDATA[this is nice]]></descr>
</vids>
<comment allow='no'></comment>
</vidlist>
```

Comment: EDIT: After spending a lot of time and breaking my head trying to figure this out, i somehow managed to get it WORKING.

Comment: ... but I still dont understand the reason for this kind of buggy behavior. To make it work I had to remove the entire <?xml... encoding declaration line from my database, and then inserted $.parseXml() in my ajax function...var xmlDoc=$.parseXML(results); $myxml = $(xmlDoc); $("#uservidshow").text("Page Title: "+$myxml.find("vidlist").attr("title"));

Answer (score 0):

You are not posting data correctly

Use this code

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'userlist.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {'id=': extr},
                dataType: "xml", 
                  .....
```

or you can use

```
 $.ajax({

                type: 'GET',
                url: 'userlist.php?id='+extr,
                dataType: "xml", 
                  .....
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont have trouble in POSTING data(id). The problem is only when reading my xml strng. That too, only "some" portion of xml data is not being read by jquery